# Python: keep the number in a specific range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem that runs like this:
I have an integer n, let n = 30. 
I add n with another integer k. Say, k = 19
However, I want to keep n between x and y, say 20 and 35. So if n+k > 35 it jumps back to 20 at 36, then continue to add 13 (19-6=13), which the final answer is 33. 
I have already done the problem from scratch, and it's lengthy. It looks like this:

```
def plus(n,k,x,y):
   result= n+k
   if result > y: #do sth
   if result < x: #do sth
   return result
```

My question is, is there any build-in method, in any library, that helps me to do this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: i dont understant very well the problem, please, can put several examples

Comment: It's like the alphabet problem. If you are at Z and you want to move up, it returns you to A. Alphabet is easy since it's 0 to 26, but I don't know how to do it from x to y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulo operator `%` performs the kind of wrapping you're looking for. `a % b` gives the remainder from dividing `a` by `b`, resulting in the following wraparound pattern:

```
>>> for i in range(-2, 12):
...     print(f"{i} % 5 = {i % 5}")
... 
-2 % 5 = 3
-1 % 5 = 4
0 % 5 = 0
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
4 % 5 = 4
5 % 5 = 0
6 % 5 = 1
7 % 5 = 2
8 % 5 = 3
9 % 5 = 4
10 % 5 = 0
11 % 5 = 1
```

(The results you see with a negative left operand aren't what you get in most languages. Most languages would give you `-2` and `-1` instead of `3` and `4`, but the `3` and `4` answers turn out to be more useful.)

You want to stay in a range from `x` to `y` inclusive instead of `0` to `y-1`, so we need to add and subtract `x` to adjust the range `%` gives us:

```
def plus(n,k,x,y):
    modulus = y-x+1
    return (n+k-x) % modulus + x
```

Sample output:

```
>>> plus(30, 19, 20, 35)
33
>>> plus(30, 0, 20, 35)
30
>>> plus(30, 5, 20, 35)
35
>>> plus(30, 6, 20, 35)
20
>>> plus(30, -10, 20, 35)
20
>>> plus(30, -11, 20, 35)
35
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking for the modulo operator: %

result = x + (n + k - x) % (y - x + 1)

Answer (score 0):

After reading your response, you can try that loop

```
def plus(a, b, minvalue, maxvalue):
    plusresult = a + b
    while plusresult > maxvalue:
        plusresult -= maxvalue - minvalue
    return max(plusresult, minvalue)
```